# pure css to scale position absolute li top and left previously set in px for responsive site

Tags: css, responsive-design, drupal-7

Is there a way in pure css to override an item that is already positioned absolute in px to a percentage so that it will be responsive.

I have a drupal module (simplePinMap) that sets pins on a map in the admin using px. Giving them a fixed top and left position via px in a ul, li.

The problem is when I make the base map responsive the pins do not scale proportionally to the map since the script sets them as px rather than a percentage. Is there some way to make the absolute positioned top and left scale or convert to percentage without editing the module script?

```
    <div id="simplepinmap-map">
<img id="simplepinmap-map-image" typeof="foaf:Image" src="availabiltymap.png" alt="Simple pin map" title="Simple pin map">
<ul id="simplepinmap-pins-container">
<li style="top:179.00px;left:649.00px" id="simplepinmap-pin-0" class="simplepinmap-pins">
<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="marker5.png" alt="Test Location" title="Test Location"></li>
</ul></div>
```

You can see in the list item the top and left are set as an element style.

Here is what the css looks like

```
element.style {
    top: 384.00px;
    left: 478.00px;
}
#simplepinmap-map #simplepinmap-pins-container li {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
}
#simplepinmap-map #simplepinmap-pins-container, #simplepinmap-items-container {
    list-style: none;
}
#simplepinmap-map #simplepinmap-pins-container {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#simplepinmap-map {
    float: left;
}
#simplepinmap-map {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

here is a link to my test: http://goo.gl/UKqlHF

Comment: I should add I have tried to reach out to the module creator without any response. I also saw several java ways to this, but outside my knowledge and hoping there is a css trick I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it may help you. Mix this css with your original css.

```
#simplepinmap-map #simplepinmap-pins-container li{
  position : absolute;
  top : 100% !important;
  left : 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work it just stacked all the pins in the same spot. Unfortunately each pin has its own unique position. Is that maybe on the wrong div?  if helpful here is a demo of the problem or map, its below the form.  [link]http://goo.gl/UKqlHF

Comment: try with this it will solve issue.

#simplepinmap-map #simplepinmap-pins-container li{
  position : relative !important;
  top : 100% !important;
  left : 0 !important;
  float : right !important;
  padding : 5px;
}